# how to remove the login prompt in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

how can i get rid of this login prompt ? it pop-ups whenever i open the report

[image]

i already made this up..

```
  obj.SetDatabaseLogon("yoyi", "yoyi", "192.168.254.9,1433", "RawrDB")
  CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = obj
```

but still the annoying window pop-ups..
im using `SAP Crystal Report 13` and `vb.net 2012`

glad from any help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ReportDocument obj= new ReportDocument();    
obj.SetDatabaseLogon("yoyi", "yoyi", "192.168.254.9,1433", "RawrDB", false);
```

You can pass the values for `SetDatbaseLogon` like this.
It will definitely works.

Comment: yup..but the window still pop-ups..is there any way to get rid of that window ?

Comment: Have you set the false parameter at last?

Comment: yup..sir..still that annoying window pop-ups..sigh

Comment: can you please rebuild your application or restart your VS. It may some visual studio problem.

Comment: that window would not appear in the server side..where the sql server installed..but in the client side..via LAN..that window always appear whenever i open the report..

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem? I am encountering the same. Even if it is the server I am working on. The connectionstring server is in a form of IP address..